# How to add information from last page to the login page and after login success redirect to last page with same information

Tags: yii

I have "create package" page, user fill data that required.
After that, when user press create button, my system will check is user has been login or not.
If user not login yet, user should be redirect to login page.
When user credential is accepted, user will be redirect to "create package" process, with same information (lastest POST data).
How to do that ?

Thanks.

Comment: which version of yii are you using?

Comment: This question doesn't show any **effort**.Try to follow yii [tutorials or demos] (http://www.yiiframework.com/wiki/51/beginner-intro-tutorials-please-add-to-update-this-list/) & when you get stuck in a specific issue your question will be more useful & you will get directed in the right way.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Store the POST data in the session,
http://www.yiiframework.com/doc/api/1.1/CHttpSession/